# Custom url for authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

Currently I have a project in ASP.NET Core with a simple authentication.

The main code was generated with Yeoman and [generator-aspnet](https://github.com/omnisharp/generator-aspnet).

The generated code has a Account Controller to authenticate the users.

Every time a user needs to log, asp.net redirect the user to http://domain/Account/Login.

Because the primary language of this site it's not english, I like to change the url to something like this:
http://domain/usuarios/login

So,  in Account Controller, I added a Route annotation on top of the class:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("usuarios")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    ...

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("login")]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidadeAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returlUrl = null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, if I go manually to http://domain/usuarios/login, the login page appears.
But, If I go to a page that need authentication, ASP.NET Core still redirect-me to http://domain/Account/Login and return a 404 error.

Checking the project.json, I see in dependencies section, the package:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
  ...
}
```

Opening the Startup class, I see in **ConfigureServices** and **Configure** methods the code `app.UseIdentity();`, but nothing about `app.UseCookieAuthentication()`

Here is a part of Configure method:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseIdentity();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

So, where I update the code to redirect to the correctly url?

PS: the generated code it's a lot like https://shellmonger.com/2015/04/04/asp-net-vnext-identity-part-2-the-login-process/

Comment: Normally your code sends 401 status code to client(i didn't understand why redirect to `Account/Login`) because you didn't specify                 `AutomaticChallenge = true,`(default is false). Try to set `AutomaticChallenge` to true or use  `[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Cookie")]`

Comment: @ademcaglin I update the question. I see after post this question that the code has a 'app.UseIdentity()'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using cookie based authentication, update your startup.cs like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{       
    services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/usuarios/login");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure `IdentityOptions` in `ConfigureServices` method like below:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(opt =>
{
      opt.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new PathString("/usuarios/login"); 
});
```